# How can I sort an array alphabetically, where prefixes show first instead of last?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I have an array populated by the following filenames (among others):

cookies, index, members-contact, members-notifications, members, social, support

This is the order PHP gives the array after using the sort function, but notice how PHP places "members" after all "members-" items. Is there a way to sort this array so that "members" shows before the "members-" items instead of after? I've tried all the sort functions available in PHP, but none can solve the problem.

P.S. Sorry for the clunky and admittedly bad subject line. I didn't know an economical way to introduce this problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour: https://3v4l.org/s0gCJ

Comment: Gotta say thanks. Your not being able to reproduce it made me go in and try to do it myself. Then I realized it's because I did a scandir, so the files were cookies.php, index.php, etc.) and then echoing it to the browser removing the extension and keeping only the filename with pathinfo. So it was sorting members-contact.php, members-notifications.php, and members.php instead of just the filenames. Thanks @Nick for the clue though!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it sorted. Those sort of things can be really hard to track down!

Comment: Heheh. Thanks. And...sorted. Pun intended? ;)

Comment: No pun intended! If you hadn't commented I probably wouldn't ever have noticed what I wrote. Pity, it would have been a good one... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was sorting based on filenames with the extension, not without (even though I was echoing the filename with no extension to the screen, which was what confused me). Since PHP orders the period after the dash (i.e. members-contact.php comes before members.php), it was sorting as it should, but I wasn't outputting the whole filename. Lesson learned: watch what you sort instead of what's being outputted.